# Why does shinycssloaders work locally, but not on the server?

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet, shinycssloaders

I have a well-functioning R Shiny app using plotly and leaflet. It is not too slow when I load the data from uncompressed .bin files - about four seconds to load - but still, it would be good to have a spinner.

The code below, using the "withSpinner" strategy, works fine on my local machine. However it does not work when I put it on my Ubuntu server. In fact, simply putting in "library(shinycssloaders)" causes the app to freeze. Does anyone know why? I do have all required dependencies.

Here is my code, with the spinner:

```
    # #### packages ####
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(geojsonio)
library(leaflet)
library(shinycssloaders)


#### TO TEST LOCALLY, use "/?COUNTRY=X&PORT=Y", eg http://localhost:PORT/?COUNTRY=CHINA&PORT=SAN%20LORENZO ####


#### shiny UI ####
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML('
      .selectize-input {
        background-color: black !important;
        color: white !important;
      }
      .selectize-dropdown {
        background-color: black !important;
        color: white !important;
      }
      .leaflet-container {
  background: none !important;
      }
      #graph-title {
        margin-top: -3px; /* Adjust this value as needed */
      }
      .leaflet-control-zoom {
        display: none;
        }
    '))
  ),
  
  column(4, align = "center", offset = 0,
         column(8, selectInput("year", "Select year", choices = c(2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019), selected = 2019, width = "100%"),
                withSpinner(plotlyOutput("granos_exportados", width = "100%", height = "440px"))), # Wrap plotlyOutput with withSpinner
         id = "graph-title",
         "click trader (above) for sources (below)",
         br(),
         
         
         # Leaflet Map Section
         column(12, align = "center",
                withSpinner(leafletOutput("leaflet_map", width = "100%", height = "500px")))) # Wrap leafletOutput with withSpinner
  
)

#### shiny server or Backend ####
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  query <- reactive({ parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search) })
##  granos_exportados <- fread('https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ecotopia.today/Data/exports_summary_full2.csv')
  granos_exportados <- read.csv('https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ecotopia.today/Data/exports_summary_full2.csv')
## save(granos_exportados, file="/home/brian/granos_exportados.bin", compress=FALSE)
##  load("/home/brian/granos_exportados.bin")
  
  pie_df <- reactive({
    granos_exportados %>%
      filter(YEAR == input$year,
             COUNTRY == query()[['COUNTRY']],
             PORT == query()[['PORT']])
  })
  
  
  top_exporter_groups <- granos_exportados %>%
    group_by(EXPORTER.GROUP) %>%
    summarise(total_tons = sum(TONS)) %>%
    slice_max(order_by = total_tons, n = 20) %>%
    pull(EXPORTER.GROUP) %>%
    unique()
  
  output$granos_exportados <- renderPlotly({
    
    # get total Soy exports
    total_soy <- pie_df() %>%
      pull(country_tons) %>%
      unique()
    
    colors <- c('#8dd3c7','#ffffb3','#bebada','#fb8072','#80b1d3','#fdb462','#b3de69',"#383689","#569DD2",'#bc80bd',
                         "#267278",'#1f78b4','#b2df8a','#33a02c','#fb9a99','#e31a1c','#fdbf6f','#ff7f00','#cab2d6','#6a3d9a')
                         ## Create a named vector of colors for each exporter group
    color_map <- setNames(colors, top_exporter_groups)
    
    p <- plot_ly(
      pie_df(),
      source = 'exporter_pie', 
      labels = ~ EXPORTER.GROUP,
      values = ~ TONS,
      type = 'pie',
      hole = 0.35,
      text = ~ DEFORESTATION,
      textinfo = 'percent',
      textposition='inside',
      hovertemplate = "%{label}<br>%{value:,.0f} tons of soy<extra></extra><br>%{text} ha deforestation risk",
      # height = 300,
      marker = list(colors = color_map[as.character(pie_df()$EXPORTER.GROUP)],
                    line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1)),
      showlegend=T
    )
    p <- p %>%
      layout(
        margin = list(t = 55, b = 0, l = 0, r = 0 ),
        title = list(text = paste(round(total_soy/1e6, 2), " MILLION TONS OF SOYBEANS<BR>", unique(pie_df()$PORT), " to ", unique(pie_df()$COUNTRY), " in ", input$year, sep = ""),
                     xanchor='center', yanchor='top', pad = list(b = 1)),
        paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        font = list(
          color = "white", size = 10),
        legend = list(
          orientation = "v",   # show entries horizontally
          xanchor = "center",  # use center of legend as anchor
          x = 0.5,
          y = -1.4,
          font = list(
            color = "white", size = 11),
          itemsizing='constant',
          itemsizingmin = 10,
          traceorder = "normal",
          itemclick = F, # here's the catch for using the OFF items to select the desired one
          itemdoubleclick = FALSE
        ),
        autosize = T,
        xaxis = list(showticklabels = F)) %>%
      plotly::config(displaylogo = F, displayModeBar = FALSE)
    p %>%
      htmlwidgets::onRender(
        "
    function(el) { 

      el.on('plotly_legendclick', function(d) { 
        Shiny.setInputValue('legend_item', d.label);
      });

    }
  "
      )
  })
  
  # Leaflet Map Server Logic
  departamentos <- geojsonio::geojson_read("https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ecotopia.today/Data/arg_provincias.geojson", what = "sp")
##  save(departamentos, file="/home/brian/departamentos.bin", compress=FALSE)
  trader_summary <- read.csv('https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ecotopia.today/Data/trader_summary.csv')
## save(trader_summary, file="/home/brian/trader_summary.bin", compress=FALSE)
##    load("/home/brian/departamentos.bin")
##    load("/home/brian/trader_summary.bin")
  
  # Leaflet map code
  df <- reactive({
    trade_df <- trader_summary %>%
      filter(YEAR == input$year,
             COUNTRY == query()[['COUNTRY']],
             PORT == query()[['PORT']]) %>%
      ungroup()
    
  })
  
  
  map_df <- reactive({
    # print(summary(df()$TONS))
    selected_trader <- input$legend_item
    print(selected_trader)
    if (is.null(selected_trader)) {
      # No legend item clicked, show all data
      df()%>%
        filter(provincia != 'IMPORTS + STOCK')  %>%
        group_by(provincia, departamento) %>%
        summarise(TONS = sum(TONS), LAND_USE = sum(LAND_USE)) 
    } else {
      # Legend item clicked, filter data
      df() %>%
        filter(provincia != 'IMPORTS + STOCK', 
               EXPORTER.GROUP == selected_trader) %>%
        select(EXPORTER.GROUP, provincia, departamento, TONS, LAND_USE) 
    }
    
    
  })
  
  output$leaflet_map <- renderLeaflet({
    
    
    leaflet(options = leafletOptions(zoomSnap = 0.25, zoomDelta=0.25)) %>%
      setView(-63, -37.5, 4.25) %>%
      addPolygons(
        data = departamentos, 
        # fillColor = 'gray',#~pal(map_dat$TONS),
        weight = 0.5,
        opacity = 1,
        color = "white",
        dashArray = "",
        fillOpacity = 0.7)
  })
  
  observe({
    departamentos@data <- left_join(departamentos@data, map_df(), by = c('provincia', 'departamento'))
    bins <- c(0, 1000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000)
    pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", bins = bins, na.color = "gray")
    
    leafletProxy('leaflet_map') %>%
      setView(-63, -37.5, 4.25) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      clearControls() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.DarkMatter) %>%
      addPolygons(
        data = departamentos, 
        fillColor = ~pal(TONS),
        weight = 0.5,
        opacity = 1,
        color = "white",
        dashArray = "",
        fillOpacity = 0.7,
        highlightOptions = highlightOptions(
          weight = 5,
          color = "orange",
          dashArray = "",
          fillOpacity = 0.7,
          bringToFront = TRUE),
        label = ~paste("<strong>", departamento, ", ", provincia, "</strong><br/>",
                       format(round(TONS/1000, 1), dec="."),
                       "K tons of soy<br>",
                       format(round(LAND_USE/1000, 1), dec="."),
                       "K ha land use") %>%
          lapply(htmltools::HTML),
        labelOptions = labelOptions(
          style = list("font-weight" = "bold"),
          noHide = F,
          direction = "top"
        )
      ) %>%
      addLegend("bottomleft", pal = pal, values = df()$TONS,
                title = input$legend_item,
                opacity = 1)
    
  })
  
}

#### RUN THE APP ####
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was devastatingly easy: install the package with the command line at the root of the server where it is available to all users:

sudo su - -c "R -e "install.packages('shinycssloaders', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')""